# What is best way to call any method after every 30 seconds

Tags: android, rx-java

i need to call a method on every 30 seconds what is the best way Handler, Observable.interval() or is there any other efficient way

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin :

```
Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
      // your code here
        }, 30000, 30000
)
```

For Java :

```
Runnable helloRunnable = () -> {
            // your code here
};

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```